# Isomorphism Between Two Matrix Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the set $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and the set of all 2x2 real matrices with determinant 1 or -1. Both those sets are groups under matrix multiplication.
Is there any isomorphism between those two groups?

Comment: Consider matrices of order 2: $A \not= I_2$ but $A^2 = I_2$. The determinant $1$ consider severely limits the options, and the only matrix of order $2$ in ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf R)$ is $-I_2$.  But the second group has additional elements of order 2, such as $(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix})$. Since the groups don't have the same number of elements of order $2$, they are not isomorphic.

Comment: It is more natural to view these as topological groups, and I want to point out that there is also a topological distinction: ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf R)$ is connected (even path-connected) while the other group is not since the subsets with determinant $1$ and determinant $-1$ provide a separation of the other group into disjoint open subsets.